# to_sql() inserting row by row despite fast_executemany=True in create_engine()

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a scenario where I need to do a bulk insert between tables, and I configured my sqlalchemy engine to do that. I configured to do a bulk insert in each chunk( chunksize: 10000 ), but I still doing inserts row by row.

```py
destengine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
               "mssql+pyodbc://"+destuser+":"+destpass+"@"+destaddress+""+destdatabase+"?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", echo=False, fast_executemany = True)

for chunk in pd.read_sql( selectquery, srcconnection, chunksize=100000):
    chunk.to_sql("MyTable", destengine, if_exists='append', index = False )
```

I selected the ODBC Driver to be the ODBC Driver 17 in my connection string as above, I put `fast_executemany` with true in my engine. What am I doing wrong? My table have millions and millions of rows and more than 100 columns. I am new in Pandas, but I think that I am doing equal to the examples.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @GordThompson, but in this case the insert is made by query, and has cursor, and the call for executemany() function. In my case I am using to_sql() of sqlalchemy to do the insert. I am doing this because I have more than 100 columns, so write a insert query would be difficult and ugly in code

Answer (score 1):

You have hit upon a variation of this:

[fast_executemany ineffective when generator passed to executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/500)

The pandas docs state that if `chunksize=` is passed to [read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) then it returns an iterator instead of a DataFrame. We can work around that by pulling the results into a "real" DataFrame and then calling `to_sql()` on that:

```py
for chunk in pd.read_sql( selectquery, srcconnection, chunksize=10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(chunk.values, columns=chunk.columns)
    df.to_sql("MyTable", destengine, if_exists='append', index = False )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did this and my trace in sql server now show incrementing the 'sp_execute' ( sp_execute 40 ex ) number, before wasn't. But...the insert still without bulk insert, doing row by row. Hundreds of inserts in each 'sp_execute number', but row by row. I have the same flow running in Microsoft SSIS and is SSIS is more than 50x faster. In Panda I am with less than 1000 rows per second

Comment: If you are looking at the trace in SQL Profiler then that's what `fast_executemany=True` looks like: an `sp_prepare` followed by a bunch of `sp_execute` calls. It doesn't do a `BULK INSERT`. For very large inserts it would probably be faster to dump the DataFrame to a CSV file and shell out to call the `bcp` utility.

Comment: Thank you again, I thought that executemany would do a bulk insert.
So, is it faster to pass data to use another lib, pass a file in the hard driver before inserting in database than work directly in memory? I am surprise. I came from C++ and SSIS, I am beginning in Python, I didn't know this 'bcp', thank you for the tip!
Is it impossible to do a Bulk Insert in a easy way with only SQLAlchemy engine and Pandas?

Comment: Running `BULK INSERT` on the server requires that the input file be "visible" to the server as well (either a local file or on a network share that the server can "see"). Most production SQL Servers are not configured to also allow file uploads (at least not in my experience).

Comment: Even the artlcles call 'bulk insert' what is not a Bulk Insert

https://naysan.ca/2020/05/09/pandas-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2-bulk-insert-performance-benchmark/